# How to check pdf check box

Tags: vba, pdf, checkbox

I am trying to read one pdf and a VBA userform and then fill out another pdf.

I wrote code to read all text in a pdf and then find certain sub strings based on tokens that I can find in the string. It is intended to populate the fields in the destination pdf based on the substrings and check the appropriate text boxes based on the user form. I can get the code to fill the substrings and then save the document, but it won't check the boxes.

Before the code used a AVDoc, but I switched to a JSO because I don't want the pdf to pop up, and the jso avoids that problem.

I tried `pdfBool.value = cBool(vbaBool)`, `pdfBool.value = 1`, `pdfBool.value = "1"`, `jso.setValue("checked")`, `jso.setValue("yes")`, etc.

This code will run without crashing.  I reduced the number of variables to one string and one bool for the sake of the example.

```vb
Sub main()

‘findString grabs all text from a pdf file.  This code works.
Dim mystr As String
If findString(mystr) = False Then
    Application.StatusBar = "Cannot find Source PDF"
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim mypath As String
mypath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\destination.pdf"
 
Dim aApp As acrobat.AcroApp
Dim pdfDoc As acrobat.CAcroPDDoc
Dim jso As Object
   
Set aApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
Set pdfDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")

If pdfDoc.Open(mypath) = True Then

    Set jso = pdfDoc.GetJSObject

    Dim vbaText As String
    Dim vbaBool As String

    vbaText = returnString("Token1")
    vbaBool = userForm.checkBox1.value

    Dim pdfText As Object
    Dim pdfBool As Object

    Set pdfText = jso.getField("TextField1")
    Set pdfBool = jso.getField("CheckBox1")

    pdfText.Value = vbaText
    pdfBool.Value = vbaBool

    'save pdffile
    Dim fileSavePath As String
    fileSavePath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\My Save File.pdf"
    pdfDoc.Save PDSaveFull, fileSavePath

    'clean up memory

    Set pdfDoc = Nothing
    Set pdfText = Nothing
    Set pdfBool = Nothing
    Set jso = Nothing

End If

aApp.Exit
Set aApp = Nothing
Unload userForm1

End Sub
```

Comment: FYI you're missing a close quote - `vbaText = returnString(“Token1)`

Comment: Not a red herring, but when I pass a string, it says there is a mismatch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after some searching, I have found a solution.  Basically, forms created using Living Cycle don't work well with checkboxes.  I asked somebody in my organization and they confirmed that Living Cycle was used on forms for a while until we got rid of it.  Honestly, I don't know what Living Cycle is, but the solution seemed to work and so I think whatever the issue was related to something called "Living Cycle".

The solution?  Redo the pdf form:  I exported the pdf to an Encapsulated PostScript file.  This stripped away all the fields.  After that, I used the prepare form tool which automatically found all the relevant fields.  Fortunately, with my pdf, it found all of the fields perfectly, though there was one or two extra ones that I had to delete.  The field names and the code need to match so adjustments need to either be made to the PDF or to the code, but once I made that adjustment, everything was perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Try jso.getfield(pdfFieldName).Value = "Yes" or "No". The value is case sensitive so you have to use Yes or No.